# MATLAB audiorecorder and wavwrite

Tags: matlab, audio, signal-processing

While reading the [website of MathWorks](http://mathworks.com) I learned that they are discouraging the usage of `wavrecord` function, because it's going to be deprecated soon, so I decided to use the `audiorecorder` instead. Everything was fine, even the play function was also playing the recorded audio, but when I use [`wavwrite`](http://www.mathworks.de/help/techdoc/ref/wavwrite.html) function to write to a wav file it's not sounding well, basically I noticed that the duration is not set properly.

I am showing the program, please suggest me how to make it correct. Thank you.

```
fs = 44100
bits = 16
recObj = audiorecorder(fs, bits, 1);
%# get(recObj)

%# Collect a sample of your speech with a microphone, and plot the signal data:
%# Record your voice for 5 seconds.
recObj = audiorecorder;
disp('Start speaking.')
recordblocking(recObj, 5);
disp('End of Recording.');

%# Play back the recording.
play(recObj);

%# Store data in double-precision array.
myRecording = getaudiodata(recObj);
%disp(size(myRecording));

%# Plot the waveform.
plot(myRecording);

wavwrite(myRecording, fs, bits,'sample01_6k');
%#wavplay(myRecording,fs);
```

Comment: Sorry, I figured out my mistake, it was very simple :-P

    recObj = audiorecorder;

the above line was creating problems, it was redundant. Now its working fine. :-)

Answer (score 0):

you are creating `recObj` twice, and the second time you create it, you create it with default settings instead of your custom settings. Remove the second call to `audiorecorder` and everything should work as expected.